# Trouble with setting up Vulkan API

Tags: api, vulkan

I want to set up Vulkan API on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 machine but it doesn't work. I followed the "Getting Started" exactly.

When I try to run vulkaninfo I get this:

```
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan API Version: 1.0.37

INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_core_validation.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_api_dump.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_parameter_validation.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_object_tracker.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_monitor.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_threading.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_swapchain.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_vktrace_layer.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_image.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_screenshot.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_unique_objects.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_i386.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/adrian/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json, version "1.0.0"

Instance Extensions:
====================
Instance Extensions count = 4
    VK_KHR_surface                      : extension revision 25
    VK_KHR_xcb_surface                  : extension revision  6
    VK_KHR_xlib_surface                 : extension revision  6
    VK_EXT_debug_report                 : extension revision  2
/home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/examples/vulkaninfo.c:1481: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

When I try to start cube I get this:

```
cube: /home/adrian/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/examples/cube.c:2789: demo_init_vk: Assertion `!err && gpu_count > 0' failed.
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

The last message means "Aborted" and then in parentheses "core dumped"

I set up the environment variables correctly:

```
export PATH=$HOME/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/lib
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$HOME/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d
```

I have the Nvidia Geforce GT 730 with the 367.57 driver which supports Vulkan

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As part of the Vulkan SDK, A Vulkan Installation Analyzer is included (VIA). Run this tool for a full analysis of your installation. If you don't understand the output, submit the output of your VIA as an issue at LunarXchange (vulkan.lunarg.com) and the LunarG engineers will assist you. You can find documentation about how to run VIA as part of your SDK installation, or view it on LunarXchange here: https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.0.37.0/windows/via.html

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do it

Comment: ./via -> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ErrorResults'
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

On linux distros, this is what happens to me if I install fake/shim driver (e.g. Mesa Intel while having iGPU disabled or Mesa RADV while my GPU is still unsupported).

Note that your card is **not** listed as supported for Vulkan on this page:
https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver